# How to set up autolayout constraints for vertical Stack View in Scroll View

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

I have the following setup, which I can't get properly to work with auto-layout:

```
Scroll View, which should take the whole screen
 |_ Stack View, which should take the whole size of the Scroll View
     |_ View 1 with a predefined height of 200
     |_ View 2 with a flexible height defined by content, but minimum 300
     |_ View 3 with a predefined  height of 500
```

I tried the following yet:

1. Scroll View

   - Set top, bottom, leading and trailing alignment to superview
2. Stack View

   - Set top, bottom, leading and trailing alignment to superview (Scroll View)
   - Set equal width to superview (Scroll View)
   - Set equal height to superview (Scroll View) with priority 250
3. The 3 Views inside Stack View

   - Define height = 200 for View1 and height = 500 for View3
   - Define height >= 300 for View2

And I get:

- an error in IB: Inequality Constraint Ambiguity for the View2
- if I launch and scroll I get additional spacing at the top and the bottom (see the red areas on the top and bottom in the simulator screenshots)

Please see the screenshots:
[image: Constraints for Scroll View]
[image: Constraints for Stack View]
[image: Predefined height constraint]
[image: Flexible height constraint]
[image: Additional space at the top]
[image: Additional space at the bottom]

Comment: i suggest u to use tableView

Comment: Can you check the properties of your UIStackView and add the 'distribution'? What you explain can happen if the distribution is not "Fill" (which is the one that you should actually choose)

Comment: @Renaud: Thanks for the hint. I changed the Distribution now to "Fill Proportionally" and the constraint error went away, also the 3 views are stacked from the top with no space in between in the IB like on the screenshots. Now I am just left with the spaces above and below the scrollview, but I think this is how iOS handles that for the iPhone X with the notch?

Comment: Fill Proportionally might not be a right choice: if you center view grows, the top and bottom view will shrink so that the height ratios between the top/middle/bottom views as defined by the constraints will be respected, but the absolute sizes won't. For the spaces above and below the scrollview, you can adjust it with the `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` UIScrollView's property. The issue is that you UIStackView height constraint can't be respected: it's broken because of the adjusted content insets and your middle view is left with only a min constraint to define its height.

Comment: @Renaud Actually I tried, and with the Fill Proportionally it works. What happens is that the Stack View and the Scroll View heights increase as well, because the Stack View's height constraint is equal to the Scroll View's height but with a low priority, so the content of the Stack View will define the height.

Comment: Ok, good to know that it works. To have it working with Fill would have actually required to change a bit your constraints, and not sure it can be done with IB (the UIStackView's height should be defined as weakly equal to the UIScrollView's layoutMarginsGuide's height), but it is easier as you have done.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Change the top, bottom, leading and trailing alignment to **SafeArea**

Because content view always inside the SafeArea.

Comment: This worked for me. Previously it was constrained to superview.top, but changing ScrollView.top == safearea.top made it become flush with top of screen